# Android Stdio Designer not working with Material design?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just downloaded the latest Android Studio v0.8.2.
When creating a new Project and setting the Theme to "Material", the designer just shows the following error.

Is there an easy way to fix this? Or do I have to wait for an updated Android Studio?

> Rendering Problems
>
> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>
> - com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView (Open Class, Show Exception)
>
> Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or
>   show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not find layout
>   resource matching value 0x1FF0006 (resolved name:
>   action_bar_home_material) in current configuration.   at
>   android.content.res.BridgeResources.throwException(BridgeResources.java:693)
>     at
>   android.content.res.BridgeResources.getLayout(BridgeResources.java:271)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)   at
>   com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.(ActionBarView.java:198)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)   at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.ActionBarLayout.(ActionBarLayout.java:97)
>   Copy stack to clipboard  File /Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/sdk/platforms/android-20/data/res/drawable/item_background_borderless_material.xml
>   does not exist (or is not a file) (2 similar errors not shown)
>   Exception raised during rendering: Color value '/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/sdk/platforms/android-20/data/res/color/primary_text_material_dark.xml'
>   must start with #